# Two switch forward converter with transient spikes on gate to source voltage

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, ringing, spike

I have a problem with my two switch forward converter.

As soon as the current increases at the input from around 200mA, a transient/spike starts appears at both the turn-on and turn-off of Vgs. The higher I go and push it the bigger the spikes get.  This is problematic as I need to get up to around 2A and 323V at the input.

I've tried increasing Rg from 10 ohm to 82 ohms.  It helped a bit. I haven't tried higher as it is already quite high. I have a diode conducting back over Rg and a 10kOhm pull down resistor. I am using an HCPL 3120 as my gate driver. Adding a DC link capacitor very close to the switches helped take away some ringing after the spike.

In the image Vgs (yellow) and Vpri (blue) over the transformer.

[image]

[image]

Here is a picture of my physical circuit. For the PCB design, I forgot to add the negative of the gate driver to the source of the MOSFETs, so I used external wires.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Gate drive circuit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Full schematic, please. `As soon as the current increases at the input from around 200mA` how? Do you mean by loading the converter (i.e. increase output loading)?

Comment: Do you consider that this question can be answered without a proper schematic?

Comment: @RohatKılıç I have added the PCB design and bottom of board

Comment: With concern to the 200mA input current, I am using a 400VDC supply and putting power into the system. The output is connected to a 800W resistor. So as I increase in input voltage staying at 40% duty cycle. The input current increases and I witness these spikes start appearing at around 200mA and gets worse from there.

Comment: Oh dear, a single sided layout! Very loose placement. Yes, ringing is what happens. You will see juicier transients on the drain waveforms, or switching loop current. Wow, that's one heck of an inductor; litz too? Well, it'll sure run cool I guess!

Comment: Sorry, this will be borderline impossible with a single sided PCB. Four layer PCBs are available for a few USD. I’d recommend one with signals on top and bottom for ease of patching, ground and Vcc on inner layers. Make the switching loop area as small as possible.

Comment: I am from South Africa so getting a proper PCB made isn't possible for cheap, especially just once off. So this is for a university project. I have been able to make a 670W full-bridge converter this way. So yeah less than ideal. But as it is, its what I need to deal with, and the thing holding me back is that transient. If you all perhaps know of a method to deal with it just enough to not destroy the circuit, I'd appreciate it greatly

Comment: JLCPCB, PCBway and others ship all over the world, including South Africa. If your layout would be extremely tight with lots of local decoupling and wires, maybe just maybe you would be able to pull it off with single layer.

Comment: Why did you remove the pictures?

Comment: @PowerSayan - Hi, It is considered vandalism to remove important information from a post (even if it's your question). Another user has kindly rolled-back your destructive edit. Please don't do that again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider this worst-case loop for example:

[image]

When Q2 turns off, the current flowing in this loop suddenly changes direction, and thus a large EMF develops around the enclosed area (and nearby).  The figure appears to be around 180 DPI so we can measure the wider loop as about 2.1 x 2.2", the smaller loop as 0.9 x 1.5", and W1 appears to rise quite far above the board so add some extra for that as well.  Round loops of about these dimensions give inductance on the order of 75 and 40nH respectively, and, let's say 30nH for W1, for a total of 145, round it to 150nH then.  (There's also a good 10nH or so for each TO-220, but whatever.)

If for example, we have 4A switching in 50ns, 80A/us through 150nH is 12V dropped.  Not very threatening to Vds ratings fortunately, but the C<sub>oss</sub> of the [IPP60R360P7](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPP60R360P7-DS-v02_03-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46259d9a4bf015a5be590fa3cc2) and C<sub>J</sub> of the diode -- which, uh, did you mean to put in 200V parts, BYV79E-200?? -- form a resonant circuit in this loop which will resonate at quite high frequency, in response to step changes.  (Note that, due to the snappy effect of the transistors' C<sub>oss</sub>, the V<sub>DS</sub> rise/fall edge can be many times faster than for current.)  This is true at turn-on as well, give or take if load current appears immediately, or delayed by significant leakage in T1, and how that current distributes through the loop.

And note that a portion of this loop is common between any likely oscilloscope probe targets, and the mains input (which has no filtering whatsoever), so we can reasonably expect a huge amount of common-mode noise as well.  Maybe not huge in comparison to the output switching waveform, but a significant part of the gate signal perhaps.  In other words: what you measure, might not be the actual gate waveform at that point in the circuit, but worse still, the act of connecting the probe to measure it, actively worsens signal quality (that is, because of CM current through the ground clip).

Put another way: presumably you have an isolation transformer in front of this thing, and yes it's galvanically isolated (i.e. at DC/mains freq.), but when is isolation not isolation? When the impedance across the barrier is significant.  There is capacitance, and also the wiring, the board itself, or the scope and probes (if they are isolated instead / as well), have capacitance, and so the whole matter of isolation goes somewhat out the window as frequency goes up.

Common mode is easy enough to recognize by probing: simply probe the ground clip.  One assumes a short-circuited probe reads nothing, but in fact the ground clip itself has inductance (and the cable is also "leaky" to some extent) and thus you're reading the voltage drop along that wire, as a consequence of high-frequency currents flowing in the loop between oscilloscope and EUT input, output or other connections.

You can also read loop voltage by shorting out the probe in this way, and hovering the resulting one-turn loop antenna over the circuit.  You will measure significant transients around the highlighted area.

---

As for what to do with it?

Frankly, I never would've built the PCB as shown; it should've gone through a design review, back and forth until an acceptable layout is had.  This is, of course, not a luxury students typically have, and you can -- and should indeed -- consider this part of the learning experience.  (So, citing these answers in your report/thesis would be prudent, as well. :) )

A single-layer build is still not unreasonable at this power level, but two or more is much easier to lay out and debug, and is essentially no extra cost (1 vs. 2 layers that is; 4 vs. 2 is about double cost, kinda for obvious reasons).  Assuming of course you have proto services available (are Chinese vendors really not available down there?).  But even a hand-made board (as this appears to be!) is reasonable to make in 2 layers, given some extra considerations about thru holes (since edge plating is several extra steps, requiring some special materials); you'd probably use riveted vias, or solder wires in as vias before placing THT components, so you don't have to have their leads soldered on both sides.

The build might not be scrap outright, but it will definitely not work at best possible performance; expect compromises in efficiency and power density.

The most likely steps are to drastically shrink the loops in question:

[image]

Add the C<sub>B</sub>s in the locations shown.  0.1µF PE or PP film will be sufficient.  They might also need some ESR to dampen against the larger inductive loop; in that case, around an ohm would be appropriate, particularly on the bottom one.

RCs can be used to further dampen the loops around each component, relevant during respective turn-on / turn-off events.  Typical starting values would be 100pF and 33Ω, and adjust values until the transients are acceptable.  Note that *lead lengths must be kept short*, for the same reason as before: you want minimum inductance in these components.  Use C0G ceramic or PP film, and, probably a 1/2 to 1W metal-oxide resistor.

You can further constrain dV/dt by adding an R+C between drain and gate; the effect of this depends on gate drive resistance, with typical starting points of, let's say, 100 ohms R<sub>G</sub>, and 10pF and 1k D-G.

A ferrite bead looped over the source pin can also be used to slow dI/dt, or over the drain pin, or either diode pin, to dampen their respective loops (high frequency ringing).

---

Aside: are you sure about output current sensor placement?  If it were in series with L1, you could do average current mode control, greatly improving loop dynamics and transient/startup/fault robustness.

Comment: Wow Tim thank you a lot for you time is knowledge! So to get a proper PCB manufactured here, or even imported from china would cost a third of my entire budget. So had to make the board using heat transfer paper and ferric chloride. I do see the improvements I'd be able to make for next time. So to confirm on your solutions to help: 1. For the Cb 0.1uF caps, should I place a 1 ohm resistor in series with the resistor (and what wattage will it then dissapate)? 2. Will a cement resistor also suffice or do metal-oxide have a better capability for use as a snubber?

Comment: 3. So I presume the R+C is again in series between Drain-Gate with 10pF and 1k resistor, also did you say I must make the gate resistor a 100 ohms, currently has it as 82 ohms.  I actually have the current LEM sensor in series with the inductor, I'll look into that!  Oh and for the input diode I just reused the footprint, its actually a FES8JT-E3/45 600V. Just thank you again for your response I do appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Another thing, do you think just redesigning my transformer with a lower leakage could also help. It currently has 7uH of leakage at the primary side.

Comment: Film resistors are better because they have lower inductance than wirewound. Noninductive wirewound are probably acceptable. Cement types tend to be bulky so add more loop length, even if "noninductive". The Cb resistors should dissipate little, but both depend on switching frequency, \$P = F_{sw}C{V_{pp}}^2\$ (for R*C << 1/Fsw). Rg in the 10-100 range is probably fine, 100 was an example value. 7uH is probably fine for a 2-sw forward.

Comment: That loop should be 1 m in circumference.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have left out two vital connections shown in red below: -

[image]

Without these connections you cannot possibly be driving the gates of the two MOSFETs correctly. The connections from the HCPL drivers that are missing (in red) should directly connect to the source pins for each MOSFET.

And, I have to say that I'm surprised because, your little hand sketch showed them connected.

Comment: They're not in the schematic, possibly because then they'd be connections in the PCB, giving an impossible layout; though there is at least one jumper shown (W1) so this may be an oversight. In any case, it seems this was realized; they are jumpered in the photo.

Comment: Correct, the two black wires seen at the bottom of the board is what I used to bridge them as I forgot it in the design. As I said in the post: "Also for the PCB design I forgot to add the negative of the gate driver to the source of the mosfets, so I used external wires."

Comment: Schematic is king and not added words (especially when the added words are not directly connected with the schematic but are mentioned elsewhere.